# Can I use a javascript variable to set yearRange on jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to set yearRange from two javascript variables, but these variables are only set after the user selects one from multiple buttons on the page, each of which sets the variables to a specific year, so the when the user loads the page the variables won't be already set. I don't know if what I want would be possible since I'm unsure if the values of the variables would update. I think the code should look something like:

```
var startDate;
var endDate;

$(".pickdate").datepicker({
 showOn: 'focus',
 yearRange: startDate+':'+endDate,
 changeMonth: true,
});
```

Where the values for the variables are obtained from another .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can if your second js is loaded in the global scope before the code you mentioned here.

---

[UPDATE] Snippet Example: As you can see in this example, you can't select a Date after 2021 or before 2018 ! And that's what the `yearRange` option is intended to do. It's supposed to define set limits to to the Calendar.

```js
console.log(dates.enddate);
$(".pickdate").datepicker({
 showOn: 'focus',
 yearRange: dates.startDate+':'+dates.enddate,
 changeMonth: true,
});

//If already contactenated, We can write:
//yearRange: range,
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Datepicker</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script>var dates={ startDate:"2018",enddate:"2021"};
  //var range = dates.startDate+':'+dates.enddate;
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="pickdate"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Example:

```
    //settings.js
var dates={ startDate:"2018",enddate:"2021"}
```

So you just load it before your script like following:

```
    <script src="settings.js"></script> 
    //Your code comes after

$(".pickdate").datepicker({
 showOn: 'focus',
 yearRange: dates.startDate+':'+dates.endDate,
 changeMonth: true,
});
```

For other details like relative defaults, you could follow the guidelines of the [Datepicker Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)

Comment: It doesn't seem like I'm able to use something other than true/false or a string as parameters on jQuery. Whenever I try to add a variable on yearRange the datepicker just doesn't work correctly. I tried using the getter/setter method, but I'd still have to input the year manually ("2018:2021" instead of startdate+":"+endDate). Should I ask another question or I'm making something simple difficult?

Comment: Sorry I just noticed your comment ! I updated my answer with more explanations and a working snippet.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! I realized where I was doing things wrong.